Meaning of song lyrics - subject ambiguity
Song: Sugar by Mass of the fermenting dregs
本当は
甘いだけのSugar
毒されてくSugar
君のせいだなんて
言わないでよ Sugar
(Sugar is the other person) roughly translating (obviously not exactly) I could think of that in these two options… My main question is who is the singer referring with those lyrics? Herself, sugar or is just ambiguous? Im not planing on seriously translating bc I’m not a translator but i think I can’t help but think that for me that lyrics it’s kind of ambiguous so I want to find out.
Option A: “I will not say something like it’s your fault” (Sugar’s Fault)
Option B: “sugar, you don’t have to blame yourself/say something like it’s your fault”
But if you know what the band really mean with this lyrics I would love to read it 

I’d go with option B. I’m not sure about the full context of the lyrics tho.
